# Lying on resume about work history

Tags: resume, united-states, background-check

I am currently an undergrad student. One of the managers I know in a small company in the US let me use their name and say that I remote-interned there. So I added this work history in my resume/cover letter. 
Now I'm trying to apply to companies with this faked resume/cover letter. Since I don't really have any skills and I am entry level, I might as well just get into a small company as an intern or low position.

1.What are the chances of getting caught? I heard companies do background check but even when I'm an intern/low position?

2.I didnt get CPT since I didnt work in the us at that time. But if i lie that i worked in the us, is there any way for hiring companies will know that I didnt get CPT to work in the us?

To be honest, I want to lie on resume especially when the manager at that company let me do it. But what I want to know is: are hiring companies do background check to verify an intern's background even when hiring companies are just small.

fyi: I'm an international student with F-1 visa

+additional info: so the manager said he can write me a recommendation letter. Is this still dangerous?

Comment: well i guess i gave up being a decent human being at this point. i just wanna know how it will affect me legally.

Comment: @cheerio I doubt you'll find many people here willing to give advice on how to cheat the system.

Comment: @solarflare thank you for being straight to me. that's what i thought and I expected people will be harsh at me because I know this is just too wrong. anyway thanks for taking time for this

Comment: Please add a location tag. I assume by the terms you use, you are located in the US?

Answer (score 17):

**Don't** just **Don't** use that fake info.

People looking for interns know that you won't necessarily have much or any experience.

They do look for skills and motivation, like do you play an instrument or do the electronics club or chess club or astronomy etc etc

They soon find the people who are looking to make the most of the opportunity, who express an interest and communicate well.

Once there, they notice those who talk to the existing staff finding out about how things work, the process etc  Instead of congregating around the coffee machine for hours discussing the latest rap star or style fad...

Comment: Especially at this stage, a cover letter is probably more important than your CV anyway.

Comment: im the writer of question. so are you saying that they are going to do the background check? what if my company goes along with the lie?

Comment: As for background check, take a coin : toss it, if heads they will, if tails they may not or still might... if it lands on its edge they won't...

Comment: what if he said he can write me a recommendation letter? is this still dangerous? do companies do background check when there's a recommendation letter from a manager from the compnay?

Comment: In my experience, they will do a background check. That said I've only ever worked for large corporations. For smaller companies, maybe not. That said... just don't lie man.

Comment: No, no, a thousand times no, please don't do this!  One reason among many: If you ever apply for a US visa and this comes to light, you'll get denied.  They do rigorous background checks these days.

Comment: @O.Jones so you mean the government will know that I lied on resume and cover letter about fake work experience when they issue me a work visa ??

Comment: Yes, I mean US INS works *really hard* these days to find reasons to deny visas. And, even if you get the visa, you'll go through all the same things again if you apply for a green card, and again if you apply for naturalization. And, heaven forbid, if you're ever arrested you may get tossed in an immigration detention facility for months and then deported for false statements on a visa application. I wish I were exaggerating, but I'm not. **Don't put fake stuff on your resume.** Just don't.

Answer (score 9):

What you're proposing is a form of fraud.

Even if you get hired and work there for years, your employer will have grounds to dismiss you if the fraud is ever discovered, so this will haunt you *long* after the hiring process.

If you lie in other parts of your CV as well (particularly around your education) then that can even become a criminal matter in some jurisdictions.

It's a terrible idea that will get you a terrible start in your career. **Just don't do it.**

Answer (score 6):

There's no question about the ethics - it's wrong. You already know that. But since we're talking chance, some basic risk management : Considering the likelihood is only half of the process - you'll also want to consider the severity.

If you restrict your resume to the facts, perhaps you won't get an interview. I know this looks like a bad outcome at the moment, but it's a normal part of job seeking.

If you include false information - particularly listing experience for an entry level position - you'll stand out from the crowd. I know that's why you're considering it, but what that means is that the employer and your future colleagues will be interested. They'll ask questions. It's not just something that might come up in a background check - it's something that's going to keep coming up.

On to the severity. Not getting an interview is no big thing. Being shown to have been dishonest, and the poor judgement associated with that, is something with long term career limiting implications. Having conspired with the other manager makes this worse, not better. You'll certainly stand out from the crowd, but not in a way I think you'd like.

If you're not happy with what might happen if you were caught, worrying about whether or not you'll be caught is of secondary importance.